# How can I build or use chart exactly similar to YoutubeStudio analytics chart in my website ? I have provided the image of the chart

Tags: youtube, linechart, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

[image]

I have a website .
Now I want to make or use the chart exactly same like  youtube studio's chart.
I had researched a lot but I didn't found any way to do it.
I just want to add the analytic  link chart of youtube studio.
Image of chart is provided .
I want to use that chart in my website.I got some chart on chart.js and other library but didn't found exactly similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data out using the [YouTube-analytics-api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics) and use the [google charts and graphs](https://developers.google.com/chart) to create the visualization.  This its not going to be something that is out of the box.

Things to consider:

1. The YouTube analytics api only keeps data for about 90 days so you will need to store it.
2. Use service accounts [server sided web apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps).  Must use server sided language not client sided.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, do you know if it is possible to get the data for the life time of a video? I am using Bigquery data transfer service for Youtube content owner but I am getting data per day, I want to get data for example per year. any help appriciated. thanks